# pandasguiの表示がウィンドウ内に収まらない

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5, pyqt

当方pythonをあまり使用した経験がなく、初歩的な質問でしたら大変申し訳ございません。
知っている範囲で検索してみたのですが、解決できずこちらで質問させていただきます。

pandasguiを起動したところ、
以下のようなエラーとともに、起動したアプリの表示が添付の画像のようにアプリ全体がwindow内に収まらない状態となってしまっています。
パッケージのバージョンも確かめて、要件を満たしている筈なのですが解決しません。
また、出力されたエラー情報もよく理解できず困っております。

解決方法をご教示頂けますと幸いです。

> show(iris)

PandasGUI INFO — pandasgui.gui — Opening PandasGUI
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\widgets\find_toolbar.py", line 308, in resizeEvent
button.move(
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
move(self, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
move(self, int, int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'float'
<pandasgui.gui.PandasGui object at 0x000001A67B691D80>

pythonのバージョンはPython 3.10.2です。
その他パッケージのバージョンは最新に更新済みです。

[image: pandasgui_screenshot]

Comment: まだ [v0.2.13](https://github.com/adamerose/PandasGUI/tags) くらいのようですから、色々とあるのでは？ 検索して見つかるこんな記事と同様の内容になるかどうか試してみて、ダメそうならいったんPythonも含めて全部アンインストールしてから再インストールしてみてはどうでしょう？ [【PandasGUIで簡単データ解析】インストールから操作まで](https://cafe-mickey.com/python/pandasgui/), [Python PandasGUI（ノーコードEDA）でExcelっぽい感じでグラフィカルにEDA（探索的データ分析）](https://www.salesanalytics.co.jp/datascience/datascience019/), [Python未導入環境においてPandasGUIとpandas-profilingを使用可能なEDAツール『Pandas Anywhere』を作ってみた](https://qiita.com/kunishou/items/dfa0f5482bebb30ed064)

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。
貼り付けていただいたリンクを参考に動かしてみましたが、やはり変わらなかったようです。
pythonのアンインストールについても試してみようと思います。

Comment: pywin32が影響している可能性があります。pywin32のGithubサイトでpython3.10に関する問題が記載されています。同じ症状とは言えないのですが、python3.10.2の環境では、TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:がでました。python3.9ではエラーがでません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
anacondaで仮想環境作成してpython3.9でも試してみましたが、解決には至りませんでした。
また、自宅のPCでは正常に表示されたので、パッケージのバージョンとpythonのバージョンを同じものにして試しましたが、解決しなかったのでもしかするとpythonのバージョンやパッケージのバージョンの問題ではなく使用しているPC側の設定に何か違いがあるのかもしれません。
そもそもpandasguiに凝る理由もあまりないので(それでも他のツールに比べて使い勝手が良さそうだったので少し執着してしまったのですが、、、、。)、他のEDAツールを試してみようと思います。